# How do I make a very thin torus?

Tags: vertices

Sorry - beginner's question alert... I'm new to Blender and am slowly getting there, but there's a really frustrating thing I'm struggling with. How to I make a really thin torus? I know if you scale it, it scales proportionately, so have been using Alt + S to Shrink/Fatten, but it seems to snap (i.e. reduce in size by chunky increments) and never gets ultra-thin. I've tried giving it more vertices but this doesn't help. Is there a better way to draw a thin tube (think 'piece of string around a basketball' type proportions)?

Comment: have you tried to press shift while shrinking? it allows to be more precise. Also, in the Operator box, on the bottom left of your 3D view, you can type the Offset value you want

Comment: Hello :). Why not set the desired thickness when you're adding the torus?

Comment: God, that's obvious isn't it? Both suggestions worked. Nice one - thanks very much!

Answer (score 3):

When you create a primitive in the resulting dialog box below to the left you can change the minor radius adjustment. That makes the torus thinner. Look in the screenshot. You need to open the dialog box before doing anything in order to change the primitive default settings [image]

Answer (score 3):

Another way is to add a Curve/Circle and then add a Bevel in the geometry properties. Scaling the circle will change the size of the torus while changing the thickness of the bevel will change the torus thickness.